# Chaquopy: error while reading a text file from python code "No such file or directory"

Tags: python, android, chaquopy

I am using python as a backend code for some scientific programs in the android app. For that, I am using the Chaquopy plugin. I found an error "No such file or directory" when accessing the text file which is stored at "app/src/main/python/". I think this is a path issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Chaquopy 6.3.0 and later, you can access data files using a path relative to `__file__`. For example, if the data file is in the same directory as the Python file:

```
from os.path import dirname, join
filename = join(dirname(__file__), "filename.txt")
```

If the data file and the Python files are in different directories, then change the relative path accordingly. For example, if the Python file is `src/main/python/alpha/hello.py`, and the data file is `src/main/python/bravo/filename.txt`, then replace `filename.txt` with `../bravo/filename.txt`.

Source: https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/144

Comment: `dirname(__file__)` is giving this following path "_/android_asset/chaquopy/app.zip_" and still got the same error. Am I have to enable something for text file that I want to read?

Comment: You need to be using Chaquopy 6.3.0 or later. Update the version number of `com.chaquo.python:gradle` in your top-level build.gradle file.