# Unable to open "model.yml" file for structured edge detection using openCV in python through chaquopy in android studio

Tags: python, android, opencv, image-processing, chaquopy

My aim is to do find edges in an image using Structured Edge Detection using OpenCV in python and use it in android studio through chaquopy. So in MainActivity, on button click, the bitmap is passed to main function in the python file for image processing, which will return the processed image and it will be set to the imageView. But due to some reason, the "model.yml" can't be opened. The code and error is as follows:

The python file is this:

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import base64
import io

def main(data):
    decoded_string=base64.b64decode(data)
    np_data=np.fromstring(decoded_string,np.uint8)

    image = cv2.imdecode(np_data,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    g_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(5, 5),0)
    blurred_float = g_blurred.astype(np.float32)/255.0
    edgeDetector = cv2.ximgproc.createStructuredEdgeDetection("model.yml") // ERROR IS DUE TO THIS LINE
    edges = edgeDetector.detectEdges(blurred_float) * 255.0
    
    pil_im=Image.fromarray(edges)
    buff = io.BytesIO()
    pil_im.save(buff,format="PNG")
    img_str=base64.b64decode(buff.getvalue())
    return ""+str(img_str,'utf-8')
```

The code in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn;
ImageView imageView;
Bitmap bitmap;
String imageString=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (! Python.isStarted()) {
            Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(this));
        }
        btn=findViewById(R.id.btn);
        imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.sample);

        Python python=Python.getInstance();
        final PyObject pyObject=python.getModule("remove_background");

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imageString=getString(bitmap);
                PyObject pyObject1=pyObject.callAttr("main",imageString);
                imageString=pyObject1.toString();
                byte image_bytes[]=android.util.Base64.decode(imageString,Base64.DEFAULT);
                bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image_bytes,0,image_bytes.length);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        });
    }
    private String getString(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,baos);
        byte[] byteImage=baos.toByteArray();
        String encoded_image=android.util.Base64.encodeToString(byteImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encoded_image;
    }
}
```

The error that I get:

```
 com.chaquo.python.PyException: error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /home/smith/git/chaquo/python/server/pypi/packages/opencv-contrib-python/build/4.1.2.30/cp38-cp38-android_16_x86/src/opencv_contrib/modules/ximgproc/src/structured_edge_detection.cpp:432: error: (-215:Assertion failed) modelFile.isOpened() in function 'StructuredEdgeDetectionImpl'
```

I think am getting this error because it can't open the model.yml file. I have put the file in the same directory as my python script i.e. `app/src/main/python`. I am not sure about this and I feel that because "model.yml" file is not placed in the correct folder, that's why I am getting this error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chaquopy: error while reading a text file from python code "No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58832006/chaquopy-error-while-reading-a-text-file-from-python-code-no-such-file-or-dire)

Comment: @mhsmith, thanks for replying! I checked the above link. That's about opening a file in order to read it, but here, I need to pass the "model.yml" file to the function cv2.createStructuredEdge Detection which will then use the model to detect edges in the image. I am actually not even sure which directory it should be put in so that it gets recognized.

Comment: The same directory as the Python file is fine. You can still generate the filename using the same technique, no matter what you're going to do with it. Please check the link again: I've edited it to remove the irrelevant call to `open`.

Comment: Hey, that worked, thank you!